# How to write Unit Test with code coverage - Spring @Bean

Tags: java, spring, azure-ad-msal

I have a configuration class with beans

```
 @Bean
   public static IAuthenticationResult getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant() throws Exception {

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(KeyPath)));
        PrivateKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(spec);

        InputStream certStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(CertPath)));
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(certStream);

         ....

        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                Collections.singleton(scope))
                .build();
        //Need to mock this in Test
        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
        return future.get();
    }
```

I want to write a unit test to increase my code coverage.

There is a close example - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/integrationtest/java/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j/ConfidentialClientApplicationUnitT.java

But I am not using all those latest libraries.

I want simple model with mock or powermock for acquireToken and be able to create bean. Please advice

Comment: You migh like the var keyword introduced in Java 10

Comment: still using java 8. Also weblogic server cant support > 8

Comment: You can do unittests on later versions of Java as they run elsewhere than weblogic.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I will wait for an answer - how to mock - app.acquireToken